# Submeter Array Multidimensional

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tenho um Form com input checkbox e text

```
'<input type="checkbox" name="formandos_servicos[]" value="'+data['id']+'">'+
'<input type="text" name="nome_funcionario_servicos[]" value="'+data['title']+'" >'+
'<input type="text" name="naturalidade_servicos[]" value="'+data['naturalidade']+'" placeholder="Naturalidade">'+
```

Faço a contagem dos input que carregam no Form

```
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
$data[] = array(
'formandos_servicos' => $formandos_servicos[$i],
'nome_funcionario_servicos' => $nome_funcionario_servicos[$i]
);
}
```

No print_r($data) o resultado é:

```
[1] => Array
(
[formandos_servicos] => 680
[nome_funcionario_servicos] => Alberto Damião Pimenta
)

[2] => Array
(
[formandos_servicos] => 678
[nome_funcionario_servicos] => Celestino José Faria Oliveira
)
```

O resultado de [formandos_servicos] corresponde à 2ª e 3ª checkbox seleccionada.
O resultado de [nome_funcionario_servicos] corresponde ao 1ª e 2ª input text.

Alguem, por favor, sabe como se pode fazer corresponder com a checkbox com o input text ?

Comment: Veja se você incluir: $data[$i], dá certo de retornar

Comment: Obrigado André. Dá o mesmo resultado... O resultado da selecção dos input checkbox é correcta, mas o resultado dos input text não. :(

Comment: Não sei como fazer corresponder o checkbox com os input texts...

Answer (score 0):

Do grupo de checkbox com o nome "formandos_servicos[]" unicamente serão enviados aqueles que estiverem marcados(checked). Os outros elementos são enviados todos, mas a correspondência no momento de receber vai ser conforme a indexação dos checkbox recebidos. Um foreach é mais adequado:

```
foreach ($formandos_servicos as $index => $value) {
        $data[] = array(
            'formandos_servicos' => $value,
            'nome_funcionario_servicos' => $nome_funcionario_servicos[$index]
        );
}
```